# Tomcat JDBC pool instance created for each webapp

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have a tomcat JDBC pool configured (using `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory`) in the /conf/context.xml file and noticed that a separate pool is created for each app under the /webapps directory.  I don't want it started multiple times so I removed all the directories under /webapps except my custom app that uses the pool.

This solved the pool issue and my app seems to be functioning fine, but am curious if there is a preferred way to configure the pool to only be available for a specific webapp.  Also, how does removing the following webapps affect the behavior of the container: docs, examples, ROOT, manager, host-manager?

Answer (score 1):

found the answer...should have defined this in the server.xml to make it global to all /webapps/

> Tomcat specific resource configuration is entered in the  elements that can be specified in either $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml or, preferably, the per-web-application context XML file (META-INF/context.xml).
>
> Tomcat maintains a separate namespace of global resources for the entire server. These are configured in the  element of $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml. You may expose these resources to web applications by using a  to include it in the per-web-application context.